# Convert PDF to CSV or xlsx with python

Tags: python, pdf, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert the whole extension of a PDF into a CSV or an xlsx with python and I've hit a wall.

I know that there is an API called PDFTables that works perfectly but the number of documents that I would like to convert (over 400) and the fact that its use involves an economic investment that I can't afford makes its use unfeasible. There is another library that I've tried, tabula, however as far as I know it only works with the tables of the PDF.

With this problem in mind, are there any other options available?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need it to be programmatic, have you seen https://www.adobe.com/la/acrobat/online/pdf-to-excel.html?

Comment: Thank you for the alternative answer however, due to the amount of files I have to process converting each archive individually is not an option for this task.